# Configuring SQL Server dynamic SQL "IN clause" on a system with hardwired pre-assigned variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to configure a system which provides me with an area to input SQL statements. These statements can have non-SQL binding variables. It is important to notice that we cannot modify the system we are configuring.

So the system provides us with `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` witch the same system will replace with the following for execution:

- `{0}` --> `string1`
- `{1}` --> `string2`
- `{2}` --> `'string3','string4','string5'` (or as many as necessary)

The query we would configure goes like this:

```
Select col1 
from table1 
where col2 = '{0}' and col3 = '{1}' and col4 in ({2})
```

which produces this when executing:

```
Select col1 
from table1 
where col2 = 'string1' and col3 = 'string2' 
  and col4 in ('string3', 'string4', 'string5')
```

In a new requirement we have to use different columns to be filtered by these 3 parameters. So the initial idea was to use dynamic SQL.

The trouble is now with `{2}` as we could not intercept its value from the configuration box in a good enough format.

We tried to use:

```
declare @mylist
set @mylist = {2}
```

but this results in the incorrect statement:

```
declare @mylist
set @mylist = 'string3','string4','string5'
```

another attempt was to do:

```
declare @sql
set @sql = 'Select '+ @myCol1 +' from table1 where '+ @myCol2 +' = '''{0}''' and '+ @myCol3 +' = '''{1}''' and '+ @myCol4 +' in ({2})'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

but this results in the following incorrect statement inside `@sql` (the error is on the non-doubled `'` that came from `{2}`:

```
'Select col1 from table1 where col2 = ''string1'' and col3 = ''string2'' and col4 in ('string3','string4','string5')'
```

Is there an alternative for what I'm trying to do?

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: It looks like .NET string formatting placeholders, but I could be wrong - so, if your statement contains *multiple* placeholders with the same number (e.g. `WHERE col4 IN ({2}) OR col5 IN ({2})`), will they both be replaced with the same list? Also, how many different columns might we be dealing with? (Is it an easily enumerated set of possibilities)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try messing up with [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) such as :

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

declare @mylist varchar(200)
set @mylist = "{2}"

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

select @mylist /* ''string3'',''string4'',''string5'' */
```

The new string should be usable with the dynamic SQL query you provided.  See this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6521).

Comment: very interesting take on the problem... `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` was my answer! But to improve your answer I suggest you remove the `replace` statement. By just replacing the `set @mylist` line with `set @mylist = "{2}"` in your answer, my problem was addressed, Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I removed the `replace` in my answer.